# Proving the existence of minimum distance between two curves

Tags: calculus, curves, maxima-minima

> Consider the following subsets of the plane:$$C_1=\Big\{(x,y)~:~x>0~,~y=\frac1x\Big\} $$and$$C_2=\Big\{(x,y)~:~x<0~,~y=-1+\frac1x\Big\}$$Given any two points $P=(x,y)$ and $Q=(u,v)$ of the plane, their distance $d(P,Q)$ is defined by$$d(P,Q)=\sqrt{(x-u)^2+(y-v)^2}$$Show that there exists a unique choice of points $P_0\in C_1$ and $Q_0\in C_2$ such that$$d(P_0,Q_0)\leqslant d(P,Q)\quad\forall ~P\in C_1~\text{and}~Q\in C_2.$$
>
> [Source: ISI B MATH 2019 UGB](https://librarykv2calicut.files.wordpress.com/2020/02/bmath-ugb-2019-1.pdf)

I took the points $(x,1/x)$ in $C_1$ and $(u,1/u-1)$ in $C_2$ and tried using distance formula but couldn't work it out. Please provide hints/solutions that use highschool mathematics only.

Comment: Question and title disagree. Title requires to find the minimum while the question request to prove that it exists. Can you fix that?

Comment: The minimum distance lies along the common normal of both the curves.

Comment: The min distance is along a curve orthogonal to them I think the answer involves Calculus of Variations not usually included  in High school maths

Comment: Not a proof but a thought. Perhaps you can translate the curves upward by 1/2, then the two curves will Be symmetrical. Perhaps you can prove the shortest distance between them passes thru the origin. And so what then you need to do is to find the point on just one curve that is nearest to the origin.

Comment: @CharlieChang how can I prove that the shortest distance passes through the origin?

Comment: I guess you can draw the tangent line t on the point (Corresponding to shortest line l passing thru the origin) and you see the angle formed by t and l is greater than 90 degree. Draw any line l’ not passing thru the origin but has one end A in common with l, and t and l intersect at point B, then you see l’ >AB>l.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the square distance
$$
d^2=f(x,u)= \frac{(u-x)^2+u x \left[u x (u-x)^2+2 (u-x)+u x\right]}{u^2 x^2}
$$
if we make the derivatives with respect to $x$ and $u$ we get
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= -2\ \frac{u^2 x^3-u x^4+u x+u-x}{u x^3}, \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} &= +2\ \frac{u^4 x-u^3 x^2+u x+u-x}{u^3 x},
\end{align}
set the numerators equal to $0$
\begin{align}
& u^2 x^3-u x^4+u x+u-x = 0, \\
& u^4 x-u^3 x^2+u x+u-x = 0,
\end{align}
if we add and subtract these equations, we get
\begin{align}
& u x (u-x) \left(u^2+x^2\right)+2 (u x+u-x) = 0, \\
& u x (u-x)^2 (u+x) = 0.
\end{align}
Given that $u<0<x,$ the only possible solution of second equation is given by $u=-x$, and substituting in the first equation we have
$$
2 x \left(2 x^4-x-2\right)=0.
$$
Again, because $x>0,$ we have to find zeroes of
$$
g(x)=2 x^4-x-2.
$$
It is easy to see that this function is negative and decreasing from $x=0$ to $x=1/2,$ then it is increasing, and it is positive in $x=2,$ so by the Intermediate value theorem there should be a unique zero between $1/2$ and $2,$ and its value is
$$
x=1.1173490365925787\ldots.
$$

Comment: What about u? Is this a straight line? normal to both hyperbolas?

Comment: @Narasimham, as stated, $u=-x$, so the points on the two curves are $(x_0,1/x_0)$ and $(-x0,-1/x_0-1),$ where $x_0$ is the value $1.11735$ given above. We are looking for two points where the distance is minimum, not a curve.

Comment: Are the three straight lines?

Comment: Of course the minimal distance is along a straight line.

Comment: Tangents are parallel by any chance?

Comment: @Narasimham tangents are parallel: on the right curve $\mathbf{t}_1=(1,-1/x_0^2),$ on the left curve $\mathbf{t}_2=(1,-1/(-u_0)^2)=(1,-1/x_0^2)=\mathbf{t}_1.$

Comment: Thanks,  wanted to check.

Comment: I got the same answer as you without calculus using AM GM

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to the question that the minimum exists and is unique**

$C_1$ and $C_2$ are closed subset of $\mathbb R^2$. $P_1=(1,1)$ belongs to $C_1$ while $P_2=(-1,-2) \in C_2$. Therefore $\inf\limits_{(p_1,p_2) \in C_1 \times C_2} d(p_1,p_2) \le d(P_1,P_2)$.

$\Gamma = \{(X,Y) \in C_1 \times C_2 \mid d(X,Y) \le d(P_1,P_2)\}$ is bounded. Being also closed, it is compact and the distance map which is continuous attains its bound on $\Gamma$. Proving that the minimum exists.

It is unique as $\overline{C_1} = \{(x,y) \mid x> 0, y \ge 1/x\}$, $\overline{C_2} = \{(x,y) \mid x< 0, y \le -1+1/x\}$ are convex.

Comment: +1 very elegant

Comment: This question from an entrance exam for undergraduate, for this answer, one would have neede dto study undergraduate already. I suppose the point of undergraduate is finally be able to solve all these questions with ease.

Answer (score 1):

With the distance formula you get a two variables formula, and you must learn the condition for a critical point of a 2-variable function.

On the other hand, I think there is other way, that uses only high school tools. You can construct the vector joining these two generic points and then force to be orthogonal to the tangent vectos of the curves. This way you obtain two equations with two unknowns, and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Plug in the definition of $y$ and $v$:
$$ d = \sqrt{(x-u)^2+(\frac{1}{x} +1 - \frac{1}{u})^2}= \sqrt{x^2 + u^2 -xu -xu + \frac{1}{x^2} + 1 + \frac{1}{u^2} + \frac{2}{x} - \frac{2}{u} - \frac{2}{xu}}$$

AM GM'ing all the non constant terms (Note -u>0):

$$\frac{ x^2 + u^2 - xu -xu + \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{u^2} + \frac{2}{x} - \frac{2}{u} - \frac{2}{xu} }{9}\geq (2^3)^{\frac19}$$

Hence,

$$ d \geq \sqrt{ 9(2^3)^{\frac19} + 1}$$

Remark: Note that for equality all terms in am gm equal, hence $x=-u$ as noted by enzotib

Comment: If there is any mistake, please comment, I'll check tomorrow and correct any errors if there are any.

Comment: Nice solution. But I think $\frac{2}{x}, \frac{2}{u}$ need to be split up as $\frac{1}{x}+ \frac{1}{x}$ and also for the other fraction for it to work. As an alternative you could've also grouped $-xu-xu=-2xu$, the RHS would then be $2^{3/7}$.

Comment: Slight error, I've fixed it now. I had written this answer in middle of the night xD @tapi